# Escape curly brackets around a template entry when using String.Format

Tags: c#, .net, string.format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String.Format exception when format string contains “{”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118529/string-format-exception-when-format-string-contains)

Does following possible using `C#` String.Format?

Required output `"products/item/{itemId}"`

I've tried escaping braces but this does not work:

```
const string itemIdPattern = "itemId";
string result = String.Format("products/item/{{0}}", itemIdPattern);
```

Preferably something more nice than

```
string result = String.Format("products/item/{0}{1}{2}", 
                              "{", 
                              itemIdPattern, 
                              "}");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need 3 braces per side for that -- 2 for the braces and 1 for the replacement.

```
string result = String.Format("products/item/{{{0}}}", itemIdPattern);
```