# System.String Formatting

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am using standard `String.Format` method. It is using numeric objects.

```
Console.WriteLine("obj1 = {0} and obj2 = {1}", "obj1", "obj2");
```

I want to use named indexes.Like this

```
Console.WriteLine("obj1 = {o1} and obj2 = {o2}", 
                  new { o1 = "obj1", o2 = "obj2"});
```

How I can use same last code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to provide custom string placeholder for string format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102300/how-to-provide-custom-string-placeholder-for-string-format)

Comment: I don't think you have a correct requirement. What would want to use such a thing for?

Comment: V4Vendetta, I checked the other questions before posting this. It didn't recommend that page you pasted here, sorry for it.

Comment: gideon, I want use it for multi languages. Everyone cannot use numbers for formatting, names will be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you can try to use `Replace("{o1}", o1.ToString())` method,

Answer (score 2):

String.Format supports only positional (0,1,2,...) values for format string.

You'll need to write your own version to support named arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You just can't.

In the example you provided, you could make a method to do something like this:

```
private void PrintVariables(Dictionary<string, object> variables)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(
        " and ", variables.Select(kvp => string.Format("{0} = {1}",
                                                       kvp.Key,
                                                       kvp.Value))));
}
```

Usage from outside could be:

```
int num = 3;
string str = "hi";
bool b = true;

this.PrintVariables(new Dictionary<string, object>
                        {
                            {"MyNumber", num},
                            {"MyString", str},
                            {"MyBool", b}
                        });
```