# How to replace the string inside { } with new value

Tags: c#

```
string vehicleno="kl-12-22222";
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
string location = "Trivandrum";
```

I have a string from database
    string s = " (Vehicle No) has deviated from GeoFence at {Time} in {Location Name}.";

How can i show

```
kl-12-11111 has deviated from GeoFence at 12/29/2014 in Trivandrum
```

in C#?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, also show your effort. Read help center how to ask a question.

Comment: string s = " (Vehicle No) has deviated from GeoFence at {Time} in {Location Name}.";

Comment: What is the context where you are using Adding this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102300/how-to-provide-custom-string-placeholder-for-string-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could use a different string for your template, something like this would work:

```
string formattedText = string.Format(
    "{0} has deviated from GeoFence at {1} in {2}", 
    vehicleno, 
    dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), 
    location);
```

Alternatively, you could chain together Replace() calls using your template:

```
string formattedText = s.Replace("{Vehicle No}", vehicleno).Replace(...).Replace(...);
```

Comment: Thank you Alan...string formattedText = s.Replace("{Vehicle No}", vehicleno).Replace(...).Replace(...); worked... I was looking for this answer..thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Put the string output into your output method for the you want to  display it (don't know if you are console app or winforms or anything else)

```
string output = String.Format(  "{0} has deviated from GeoFence at {1} in {2}",vehicleno,dt.ToString(),location )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) method, e.g.,

```
int vehicleNumber = 123;
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
string locationName = "here";
string text = string.Format("{0} has deviated from GeoFence at {1} in {2}", vehicleNumber.ToString(), time.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy"), locationName);
```